# Whats the equivalent of this emmet code done in dreamweaver to vs code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

This was written on Dreamweaver but wont work on Visual Studio Code. Someone told me that the Emmet syntax changes from one IDE to another but Im not sure what it is.

PD.Im using Bootstrap there.

I already changed 'lipsum' to 'lorem'

```
(div.card>img[src=image/fotogr$.jpg].card-img-top+div.card-body>h5.card-title{Producto $}+p.card-text>lipsum)*17
```

I expect to create 17 bootstrap cards containing a image and a description with a title each one

Answer (score 0):

VSCode has emmet built-in. Maybe the problem is the "emmet query" itself. Try adding 2 `""` around the source image and it should work. The working query for me:

```
(div.card>img[src="image/fotogr$.jpg"].card-img-top+div.card-body>h5.card-title{Producto $}+p.card-text>lipsum)*17`
```

[image]